# ClassCastException and compilation issue in strange manner in java

Tags: java, classcastexception

The below code snippets have a strange behaviour.can anyone explain in detail please

The below code throws ClassCastException but inks.get(0) gives ColorInk which cannot be casted to BlackInk as there is no IS-A relationship.
Then compiler error should be given why is it compiling successfully and throws ClassCastException.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    public class ListAccess {
      public static void main(String[] a){
        ArrayList<Ink> inks=new ArrayList<Ink>();
     inks.add(new ColorInk());
     inks.add(new BlackInk());
     Ink ink=(BlackInk) inks.get(0);
  }
}

class Ink{}
class ColorInk extends Ink{}
class BlackInk extends Ink{}
```

The below code is again strange it fails compilation instead of ClassCastException when only Arraylist generic is ColorInk what makes the difference in both the cases list.get(0) returns ColorInk which is being casted to BlackInk where there is no IS-A relationship.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
        public class ListAccess {
          public static void main(String[] a){
            ArrayList<ColorInk> inks=new ArrayList<Ink>();
         inks.add(new ColorInk());
         Ink ink=(BlackInk) inks.get(0);
      }
    }

class Ink{}
class ColorInk extends Ink{}
class BlackInk extends Ink{}
```

Comment: Nothing strange here, the since the cast *could* be possible in the first case the checking can only be performed at runtime. In the second case there is not theoretical possibility of the cast being allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you notice is related to the basic rules of inheritancy.

For the first snippet, you downcast a `Ink` to `BlackInk` :

```
Ink ink=(BlackInk) inks.get(0);
```

The compiler accepts it as a `Ink` may be `BlackInk`.  But a downcast may still fail if the cast is invalid at runtime. That is what happens as `inks.get(0)` refers a `ColorInk`.

In the second snippet :

```
ArrayList<ColorInk> inks=new ArrayList<Ink>();
...
Ink ink=(BlackInk) inks.get(0);
```

the compiler stops you because you want to cast a object with a declared type to a type which it cannot be compatible : a `ColorInk` cannot be a `BlackInk` according to the hierarchy you defined.  The compiler doesn't wait that it fails at runtime as it may make the compilation fail right now, which is better.